# React Native how to use fast image for expo using cache

Tags: react-native

I uploaded images to firebase storage and fetching it on the display. It's working fine, but I noticed that it reloads every time changing to other page and the speed is quite slow.
So, after googling I found expo-fast-image (because I'm using expo)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-fast-image

so, after installing it, I'm trying to follow or copy the given an example, but I don't know how to use it properly. Below is my code with expo-fast-image.
Does anyone know how to use it properly?

```js
import ExpoFastImage from 'expo-fast-image';


const CustomListItem = ({id, number, data, coffeeBean, description, image, Order}) => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const name = user.displayName;
    const ImageLoad = (image, id) => (
      <View>

          <ExpoFastImage
            uri= {image}
            CacheKey={`cache.${id}`}
          />
      </View>
    )
    return (
      <ListItem key={id} bottomDivider onPress={() => {Order({id, number, coffeeBean, description, image})}} >
          <ExpoFastImage image={image, id}/>
          <Avatar rounded source={{CacheKey: `cache.${id}`}} />
          <ListItem.Content >
              <ListItem.Title style={{ fontWeight: '800'}}>{id}</ListItem.Title>
              <ListItem.Subtitle numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>
                  Stock: {number}
              </ListItem.Subtitle>
          </ListItem.Content>

      </ListItem>
    )
}

export default CustomListItem
```

Answer (score 0):

If `expo-fast-image` uses `Image` from `react-native`, images are cached and they are downloaded again only when the url changes. So in your situation, you might be giving different urls to the component which propmts it to download again. Make sure the url is always the same. Even if you add some random string like `#some-random-value` at the end of url which does nothing. It triggers the download action.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Since it's showing list of item,  url will be changing to load each image. So I was thinking it will leave cache and I can use it for fast reload, as images won't be changed unless new image uploaded. But where can I find cache? or how do i know which one is the cache for the image?